# ¿Como puedo leer el Expires de una cookie?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, cookies

Tengo una `cookie` la cual se llama `C__COOK` que contiene un valor `1` lo que necesito hacer es poder leer esta cookie por completo, me refiero con esto a su propiedad `Expires` para poder usar su valor en una condicional.

Tengo lo siguiente en mi controller donde creo la `cookie`

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Signin(LoginViewModel model)
{
    if ((model.User.ToString() == "usuario") &&
        (model.Pass.ToString() == "123123"))
    {
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(model.User, false);
        HttpCookie httpCookie = new HttpCookie("C__COOK");
        httpCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5);
        httpCookie.Value = ProtectCookieMethod("1");
        HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(httpCookie);
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Usuario incorrecto";
    }

    return View();
}
```

Luego desde mi cliente por medio de `Ajax` realizo una solicitud `get` hacia un metodo `Valid` el cual me devuelve un `json` con un valor `bool`.

```
public JsonResult Valid()
{
    if (HttpContext.Request.Cookies["C__COOK"] != null
        && HttpContext.Request.Cookies["C__COOK"].Value != null)
    {
        var x = Response.Cookies["C__COOK"].Expires.ToString();
    }

    return Json(new { isValid = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Esto deberia comparar la fecha de expiracion si es que ya caduco o no y devolver un mensaje a mi cliente con un json de tipo `bool`. El problema es que al recuperar la propiedad `Expires` de la forma `Response.Cookies["C__COOK"].Expires.ToString();` me devuelve una fecha nada que ver con puros 0 y 1.

¿Como puedo recuperar este dato?